# How to consume an API response with Swift

Tags: ios, swift4, alamofire, jsonresponse

I am trying to make an API request to get an API response  I am getting all the elements but I am facing braces issue I want a whole response and "order_devices" key, in {} braces but I am getting these in [] braces.

```
the array in which i am passing value,

var popUpArray :[[String:AnyObject]] = []
```

then on btn click  i am saving values in dictionary

@IBAction func btnSave(_ sender: Any) {

```
    let popupDict = (["quantity": Int(txtEnterQuantity.text!), "name": lblDeviceName.text,"id": deviceDict["id"], "region":1, "system_integrated":1 ])as! [String:AnyObject]
```

and then passing the same  dictionary value as parameter

```
    let passDict = [
            "dealer_id":dropDownId!,
            "client_id":dropDownId!,
            "distributor_id":searchBarId!,
            "emp_id":UserId,
            "comments":CommentKey!,
            "accepted_by":0,
            "valid_from":strDate!,
            "valid_upto": 0,
            "order_devices":popupDict
            ] as [String : Any]

            if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
            showActivityIndicator()
            Alamofire.request("http://13.232.230.41/IAC_CRM/public/api/createOrder", method: .post, parameters: passDict, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:])
                .responseJSON { (response) in
```

i am getting this response ,

> [
>         "comments": "demo",
>          "dealer_id": 3,
>         "valid_from": "6-3-2019", 
>         "distributor_id": 72,
>         "client_id": 3,
>         "accepted_by": 0,
>         "emp_id": 33,
>        "valid_upto": 0
>        "order_devices":
>                             [
>                                  [
>                                      "id": 1,
>                                      "quantity": 10,
>                                      "region": 1,
>                                      "system_integrated": 1
>                                   ]
>                                   ,
>                                   [ 
>                                       "id": 2,
>                                       "quantity": 12,
>                                       "region": 1,
>                                       "system_integrated": 1
>                                     ] 
>                               ]
>              ]

i want this response,

> { "dealer_id":"1", "client_id":"2", "distributor_id":"2",
>   "emp_id":"1", "comments":"IAC test device comments", "accepted_by":0,
>   "valid_from":"2019-01-24", "valid_upto":"1", "order_devices":[
>                     {
>                         "device_id":"1",
>                         "quantity":"1", "region":1, "system_integrated":1
>                     }
>                     ,
>                     {
>                         "device_id":"2",
>                         "quantity":"1"
>                         "region":1,
>                            "system_integrated":1
>                     }
>                 ]           }

means i want whole response and   "order_devices" key in "curly braces"{} .

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with request or response, your are getting response what your API is returning, You should ask you backend developer Or Api Provider to Give you response in form of your requirement i mean proper formatted Right now its in form of Array.

Comment: yes sir ,i am getting the proper response but the but not in correct formate and that is the issue

Comment: right now server is sending you response in form of Array object not in form of dictionary

Comment: how can i convert same data in array form ?

Comment: let data  = response as?  [[string:Any]]
let dictData = data[0] as? [String:Any]
and so on...